# Chrome extension - Unable to launch external website using Chorme*.API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to create Chrome extensions. I just started developing one to launch Amazon website and perform search activity on it. I have used content script. But my code is not working after the first alert. Please find my code below :

### > **manifest.json** : manifest file

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->

    {
      "name": "TestChrome Extension",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
       "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"]
      },
      "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
      ],

      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": [ "contentscript.js" ]
          //"run_at": "document_end"
        }
      ],

      "browser_action": {
        //"default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "That's the tool tip of extension"
      }
    }
```

### > **popup.js** : popup file/background script where I am using getElementbyId method

```
<!-- language: lang-javascript -->

   // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // Send a message to the active tab
    alert("Clicked Recognised");
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        console.log("URL from main.js", activeTab);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { "message": "clicked_browser_action" });
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.message === "open_new_tab") {
          chrome.tabs.create({ "url": request.url });
          document.getElementById("twotabsearchtextbox").textContent = "Iphone 7";
          document.getElementsByClassName("nav-input").addEventListener("click", function () {
              window.alert("You Clicked Me");
          });
     }
  }
);
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "contentscript.js", allFrames: true });
```

### > **contentscript.js** : below is the code of my content script

```
<!-- language: lang-javascript -->

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
          alert("CONTENT SCRIPT: I am running!");
         // var firstHref = $("a[href^='http']").eq(0).attr("href");
          var firstHref = "http://www.amazon.in";
          //console.log(firstHref);
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "message": "open_new_tab", "url": firstHref });
      }
  }
);
```

I have modified my script as suggested. Please see the above code.

Comment: Don't use alert, it probably makes the popup autoclose, meaning its code stops running. Use console.log and *debug the code properly*: rightclick the popup, choose `Inspect`, go to Sources, set breakpoints, step through the code, inspect the values.

Comment: Thank you.Popup is not auto-closing. I have to manually close the popup. I did debug the code but my code does not step into this this line    :            chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs)

Comment: In that case set a breakpoint inside the callback.

Comment: it is returning undefined

Comment: Most likely it means the content script wasn't injected which happens right after the extension was installed or reloaded. In that case when `request` is `undefined` you'll need to inject the content script manually using chrome.tabs.executeScript and resend the message in its callback.

Comment: thank you. now the web page is getting opened in new tab but below lines are not getting executed. What I am trying to do here is I want to search the value in webpage and click of search button it should invoke a alert message.                                                                                   document.getElementById("twotabsearchtextbox").value = "Iphone 7";
          document.getElementById("nav-search-submit-text").addEventListener("click", function () {
              window.alert("You Clicked Me");
          });